# rt patch for latest stable 3.17.4 vanilla kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, patch, real-time

I want to apply an rt patch to the latest stable vanilla kernel, which is 3.17.4 currently. The latest rt-patch found are for 3.14.24. Does that mean I have to use the the 3.14.x family, and can not use 3.17.4 ?
Reason being; from above 3.15.x, my sound-card are working properly.
Thank you.

This is btw the link for the rt patches: 
https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/

Comment: what sound card do you have? Is it possible to compile the latest `alsa` to get support for your sound card instead of upgrading the kernel? also are you SURE you need a real time kernel and a preemptive kernel is not good enough? for the vast majority of audio related use cases a preemptive kernel will suffice. Also are you flexible on distro usage? I am sure `ubuntudtudio` kernels are compiled preemptive by default.

Comment: Hi nass, I have a Saffire USB 6. Don't know about the latest alsa, but I think they came with some important updates after the 3.15.x version included in the vanilla source. Reason being for the rt kernel, are mostly test purposes...when i will use the system for live perfomances (e.g with a midi keyboard), the latency is what I think about. At the time I am testing out the KXStudio, which is ubuntu software.

Comment: See the [FAQ Section - What is the "3.x stable RT tree"?](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Frequently_Asked_Questions) for the reason the RT Kernel lags behind the mainline.

Comment: @Nicco with an ordinary preemptive kernel, I get jack to run without any xruns at 5msec. even 2msec with only clicks when i load a new effect or synth. I really don't think you need to even attempt the rt-kernel. Even if i'm wrong, you can still try out the preemptive one until a patch for >3.15.x kernel comes out. shouldn't be too long.

Comment: Ok @nass, maybe that's a good idea. Thank you for sharing. And thank your the link eyoung100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need an `rt-kernel` you will have to wait for a patch to become available for the version of kernel you seek.

I would advise however to avoid the hassle of preparing an `rt-kernel` for your professional audio needs. You can easily get extremely low (<10msec) latencies even with the preemptive kernel. This should be more than enough.